# Find a collection of sets such that there is maximum intersection of elements among the selected sets

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, set, set-intersection

I have roughly  300,000 (300K) sets, each containing 0-100 elements.

```
s1={a,b,x,y}
s2={a}
s3={a,x,y}
s4={x,y}
```

My question is, How do I efficiently find a collection of sets (say I need a collection 5000 sets from 300K sets) where there is maximum intersection of elements among those selected sets?
 
i.e.
Among all possible combinations of 5000 sets that can be picked from 300K sets, I need that one collection of 5000 sets such that intersection(number of common elements) among it's 5000 sets is greater(>=) than any other combination of 5000 sets that are possible from 300K sets.

For example : From the sets shown above,

- Say I need 2 sets where there is maximum intersection of elements among them.The resulting collection would be ->  C = {s1,s3} with [common elements={a,x,y}, common elements count=3]
- Say I need 3 sets where there is maximum intersection of elements among them.The resulting collection would be -> C = {s1,s3,s4} with [common elements={x,y}, common elements count=2]

Bruteforce method is not an option since the total number of possible combinations of 5000 sets from a collection of 300K sets is huge.

```
300K choose 5000 = O(10^11041)
```

Are there any smart data structures and algorithms that I can use to get the desired collection of sets?

Also, is there are any available python library that I can use for this?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I can't do brute force as I mentioned in the question itself. I had been searching online & on Google scholar , hadn't found useful literature to go on further, hence asking here.

Comment: I dont think this is solvable much faster than brute force. This problem is at least beyond NP because not only is it difficult to find a solution, it is difficult to even verify a solution. It would be solvable quickly if you were willing to accept a collection of any size, not judt exactly 5000

Comment: If you were able to sort them by size and start checking the intersection size of the larger ones, when you get the first 5000 intersections, you'd be in a position to discard all the sets that are smaller than the smallest intersection. Worst case scenario would still be = to brute force, though.

Comment: There is no efficient solution for this. You can make some optimizations like removing elements that do not appear at least 5000 times, and keep track of best solution so far and discard sets with lower size than that, but would still take a long time to run. You could try to model it as an integer programming problem, which may be better than brute force but will probably take too long as well

Comment: [A bit of literature](https://research.tableau.com/sites/default/files/kdd_sketch_merge.pdf)

Comment: @juvian thanks for the points, I'll check these out. Could you expand or give resource link on how to use integer programming for solving this?

Comment: I think the question most closely relates to 'optimal subset selection' problem which is NP-hard. I am hoping to find a decent approximation for current case that is implementable for practical use.

Comment: @jaggi I am not well versed in it, tried yesterday but got stuck modeling it. Also you have too many sets, even checking each pair intersection will already take too long.